# How to detect if a control was enhanced by jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

For example, if you try to call

```
$(element).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

on a checkbox that wasn't already enhanced by jQuery Mobile, it raises an exception saying that you cannot call 'refresh' on uninitialized elements.

jQuery Mobile requires you to call 'create' on non-enhanced elements and call 'refresh' on enhanced elements but doesn't provide a documented way of checking out if an element was enhanced or not.

So, is there a way to detect it, short of catching the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JQM code that raises the exception, I see that JQM internally determines the state by checking the $(element).data("mobile-checkboxradio") for some object. If it's not there, then it raises an exception.

So this seems to work just fine:

```
if ($(element).data("mobile-checkboxradio"))
    $(element).checkboxradio('refresh');
```